# CSV File display a string input

Tags: python, csv

I have created a Tkinter app to store the data in CSV file. The code as follow:

```
def add_file():
    global msg
    msg = entry.get()
    print(msg)
    if msg != '':
        listbox_tasks.insert(END, msg)
        entry.delete(0, END)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Info', 'Please Fill In The Entry Box!')

def save_file(msg):
    with open('hello.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow([msg])
    messagebox.showinfo('Info', 'Message Saved!')

scrollbar_tasks = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox_tasks = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set, height=12, width=32, 
                         font=('Helvatica', 18))
listbox_tasks.pack(pady=20)

entry = Entry(label_frame1, font=('Helvatica', 18))
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

my_create = Button(label_frame2, text='Add File', 
                   font=('Helvatica', 15), command=add_file)
my_create.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

my_entry = Button(label_frame2,  text='Save File', bg='green', fg='#ffffff',
                   font=('Helvatica', 15), command=lambda:save_file(msg))
my_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
```

When I enter 1,Apple in entry and clicked save file button, in my CSV file display as "1,Apple" instead of 1,"Apple".

How could I strip out the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This writer function splits decimal data (not quoted) and other data (quoted).

This is the writer function:

```
decimals = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.'}
def save_file(msg):
    with open('hello.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        msg += ","#ending char
        formatted = ''
        quote = False
        block = ''
        for i in msg:
            if i not in decimals:
                if i != ",":
                    quote = True
                    block += i
                else:
                    if quote:
                        block = '"'+block+'"'
                    formatted += block
                    formatted += ','
                    #new block
                    quote = False
                    block = ''
            else:
                block += i
        formatted = formatted[:-1]#remove ending char
        f.write(formatted+"\n")

    messagebox.showinfo('Info', 'Message Saved!')
```

When I use this:

```
msg = "2,gerry,2.2,erderrer,42.0,22hellohelloh4llo,123.456789"
save_file(msg)
```

I get this in the CSV file:

```
2,"gerry",2.2,"erderrer",42.0."22helloh4llo",123.456789
```

The line is ending with a newline character.